# Typescript issue when passing in specific strings

Tags: typescript

What is the issue with `str` below on line `15`? I would have imagined the Typescript compiler can see that `str` will always be `'foo'` or `'bar'`

```js
import { useEffect } from 'react'

type Type = {
  name: 'foo' | 'bar'
}

const Demo = () => {
  const update = ({ name }: Type) => console.log('logging: ', name)

  useEffect(() => {
    const arr = ['foo', 'bar']

    arr.forEach((str) => {
      update({
        name: str,
      })
    })
  }, [])

  return null
}

export default Demo
```

But the Typescript compiler says...

```
(property) name: "foo" | "bar"
Type 'string' is not assignable to type '"foo" | "bar"'.ts(2322)
file.tsx(4, 3): The expected type comes from property 'name' which is declared here on type 'Type'
```

Comment: `arr` is just `string[]`

Comment: editing it to `const arr: string[] = ['foo', 'bar']` doesn't fix this

Comment: Why would it? That's the same as the inferred type, which you already know isn't working.

Comment: I didn't know this was why it wasn't working. I can see below `const arr: ['foo', 'bar'] = ['foo', 'bar']` or `const arr = ['foo', 'bar'] as const` solves it

Answer (score 2):

Your type is not narrowed enough.

`const arr = ['foo', 'bar']` is considered of type `string[]`.

Use one of the two below to get the right type:

1. The correct type

```
const arr : ['foo','bar']= ['foo', 'bar'];
```

2. [const assertion](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-3-4.html#const-assertions)

```
const arr = ['foo', 'bar'] as const;
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ssl=11&ssc=5&pln=13&pc=1#code/JYWwDg9gTgLgBAbzgVwM4FMCiAzb6DG8AvnNlBCHAORToCGhVAUEzAJ5jpwAqHXAvIiZw4AOzoh0ALmrYIEKnAA+1AEZ0ozIi3wRRqeABF0ICHEEAKAJTmAfEJG798ZGAAmdGALgWk4yXBEMrycNvz2TqgQADboAHTREADmFlSJSUnAokkyVAA0YhLoViwiaFi4BDAW1nYOInCR8BpQcDIA2lRyCnlU6poAuoKd3flqGlQDANzCIgD0c416BnAt5nAj8mN9EwOrqEvOM7MiLXFyUJgMABY1BlBh9ggnDa4eXr4vDYWSMvd5X0CJW+RGBgQK7QGJVmtBgyCgojEyGi0SY2iY6AAHpBYHA3OhsHRkUYTBAgA)

Answer (score 0):

The inferred type of `arr` is just `string[]` because [there is a single "best common type"](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/type-inference.html#best-common-type).

Add an explicit type annotation to make the type more specific:

```
    const arr: Type['name'][] = ['foo', 'bar']
```